# How to change Google's display of a website name

Tags: wordpress, seo, title, meta

I have a Wordpress site named Prairie Health Ventures. Currently, all what I would like to do is just change how Google displays the name as "Prairie Health Ventures" to "Prairie Health Ventures – Advancing Healthcare Through Collaboration". I've tried searching around a bit and have found mention of using 'meta' and 'title' tags. I've tried erasing what Wordpress currently has in place and putting my own but Google just displays "Prairie Health Ventures" still.

I'm new to coding and a friend of mine directed me towards this site for help. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already changed the title of your page (it appears in the browser's title bar), you can get Google to pick up the change through Google Webmaster Tools, in the following steps:

1. Sign up for Google Webmaster Tools - http://google.com/webmasters/tools/
2. Add your site and verify it
3. Once verified, go to "Site configuration", then "Crawler access", then "URL removals"
4. Create a removal request for the page in question
5. Wait for Google to remove the page from its index and recrawl it in time

When I did this the last time, it took a few hours for Google to update its index.